# Using virtualenv with VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I tried to open a python script with VS code. The library that requires with the script is in a virtualenv.

I am not sure how to integrate this with VS Code. I could not find my virtualenv in the intepreter.

For your information, the virtualenv I created is called "vc-web" and the scripts is in the folder called "web_scraper" inside the "vc-web" folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is in folder e.g. `proj`, and you have a virtual environment at `proj/vs-web` and it's the only virtual environment in that directory, then it should be listed by the `Python: Select Interpreter` command where you can select it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just specify the "python.pythonPath" as follows. The values for "python.autoComplete.extraPaths" will be determine during runtime, however you are still free to specify custom paths in there.

Please remember to re-start VS Code once the necessary changes have been made.

```
{
    "editor.rulers": [80,100],
    "python.pythonPath":"~/path/to/venvs/proj/bin/python"
}
```